# How does Token Authentication Server work in .Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I am learning Angular and Web API endpoint in registration will create a token and return it to the client.

Here is the code:

```
 var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

 var claims = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.UserName)
 });

 const string secretKey = "your secret key goes here";
 var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(secretKey));
 var signinCredentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);
 var token = (JwtSecurityToken)tokenHandler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(subject: claims, signingCredentials: signinCredentials);

 var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
 return new JwtPackage()
                {
                    UserName = user.UserName,
                    Token = tokenString
                };
```

I have read about https://oauth.net/2/

I know that the Authorization server should create the token. Here I am creating the token myself and return it to the user using `JwtSecurityTokenHandler`.

My question: is this implementation the correct one to follow up with the https://oauth.net/2/ ?

If it yes, so where is the authorization server?

Also If I do not encrypt the token, and save it in local storage. is this safe ?

Comment: Since you seem to be making your own password storage, I think this is a worthwhile watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q

Comment: @Christopher I can undestand I am not following the https://oauth.net/2/

Comment: Somebody made a toutorial for OAuth 2.0 and .NET: https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/authenticate-oauth-aspnet-core-2/